# paste function of ActionChains through keyboard not working in gsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

`driver.get("gsheetlink")`

`time.sleep(5)`

`act=ActionChains(driver)`

`act.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

`time.sleep(5)`

I want to paste in google sheet from another website through python script without google sheet api.
The script ran successfully but not pasting the copied data to the gsheet.
Other keys like: TAB, ENTER, etc. works

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.